# PHP/MySQL Multidemensional/Associative Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, mysqli

I have this code that fetches data from mySQL and outputs it as an array(multidimensional) like so:

```
$res = @mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT id, subject, exam, marks, remarks  FROM log WHERE student = '2222' AND term = 'Term2'");
$studentMarks = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $studentMarks[$row['subject']][$row['exam']] = $row['marks'];
}



//So far the code displays $studentMarks like this:
//$studentMarks = array(
//    Maths => array('CAT1' => 50, 'CAT2' => 35)
//  , English => array('CAT1' => 20, 'MIDTERM' => 40)
//);

//I wish it to add remarks thus displaying $studentMarks like:(Not sure whether I am right)
//$studentMarks = array(
//    Maths => array('CAT1' => array(50,
//          "Good"
//          ), 
//      array('CAT2' => array(35,
//          "Can do better"
//          )
//)
//  , English => array('CAT1' => array(20,
//          "Good"
//          ), 
//      array('MIDTERM' => array(40,
//          "Much better"
//          )
//);

echo '<table><thead><tr>';
echo '<td>Student</td><td>CAT1</td><td>CAT2</td><td>MIDTERM</td>';
echo '</tr></thead><tbody>';



foreach($studentMarks as $studentSub => $marks)
{
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>', $studentSub, '</td>';
  echo '<td>', (isset($marks['CAT1']) ? $marks['CAT1'] : '&nbsp;'), '</td>';
  echo '<td>', (isset($marks['CAT2']) ? $marks['CAT2'] : '&nbsp;'), '</td>';
  echo '<td>', (isset($marks['MIDTERM']) ? $marks['MIDTERM'] : '&nbsp;'), '</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</tbody></table>';
```

//END CODE

I am trying to achieve this:

SUBJECT   CAT 1 | CAT 2 | MIDTERM | ENDTERM

MATH           50         35
                  Good     Can do better
ENGLISH  20                       40
                  Can do better    Do better

QUESTION:

How can I display remarks under/against each marks displayed?

Your Help is Much Appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$res = @mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT id, subject, exam, marks, remarks  FROM log WHERE student = '2222' AND term = 'Term2'");
$studentMarks = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $studentMarks[$row['subject']][$row['exam']]['mark'] = $row['marks'];

    //This will get the remarks from the database
    $studentMarks[$row['subject']][$row['exam']]['remark'] = $row['remarks'];

    //This should be used when you chose to compare marks and display appropriate remarks
    //$studentMarks[$row['subject']][$row['exam']]['remark'] = ( $row['marks'] < 40)?'can do better':( $row['marks'] < 50)?'do better':'good';
}


    echo '<table><thead><tr>';
    echo '<td>Student</td><td>CAT1</td><td>CAT2</td><td>MIDTERM</td>';
    echo '</tr></thead><tbody>';



    foreach($studentMarks as $studentSub => $marks)
    {
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td>', $studentSub, '</td>';
      echo '<td>', (isset($marks['CAT1']) ? $marks['CAT1']['mark'] : '&nbsp;'), '</td>';
      echo '<td>', (isset($marks['CAT2']) ? $marks['CAT2']['mark'] : '&nbsp;'), '</td>';
      echo '<td>', (isset($marks['MIDTERM']) ? $marks['MIDTERM']['mark'] : '&nbsp;'), '</td>';
      echo '</tr>';

      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td> </td>';
      echo '<td>', (isset($marks['CAT1']) ? $marks['CAT1']['remark'] : '&nbsp;'), '</td>';
      echo '<td>', (isset($marks['CAT2']) ? $marks['CAT2']['remark'] : '&nbsp;'), '</td>';
      echo '<td>', (isset($marks['MIDTERM']) ? $marks['MIDTERM']['remark'] : '&nbsp;'), '</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</tbody></table>';
```

Comment: Thanks mahadeb for your answer, though I meant that the remarks are already in the database. How do I fetch the remarks from database and display against the marks?

Comment: I managed to solve the code...all I did was remove the remarks comparison and replaced it with $row['remarks'] like this: $studentMarks[$row['subject']][$row['exam']]['remark'] = $row['remarks']; . Thank you so much mahadeb. I can safely say problem solved.